# Distinct query isn't giving any results with AND operator

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Here is the query that i am trying to execute, but i get no results, if you need more information to help regarding this kindly ask in the comments below i would appreciate any assistance Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM `users`  
WHERE ((`height` BETWEEN "139" AND "170" 
        AND `language` = "english")  
       AND (`active` = "1" 
            AND `gender` IN (4525, 4526) 
            AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`) / 365 >= "22" 
            AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`) / 365 <= "55" 
            AND `country` = "IT") 
       AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `block_userid` 
                        FROM `blocks` 
                        WHERE `user_id` = 1)  
       AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `like_userid` 
                        FROM `likes` 
                        WHERE `user_id` = 1)  
       AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` 
                        FROM `likes` 
                        WHERE `like_userid` = 1)  
       AND `id` <> "1" )  
ORDER BY 
    `xlikes_created_at` DESC, `xvisits_created_at` DESC, 
    `xmatches_created_at` DESC, `is_pro` DESC 
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0;
```

I tried OR operator but certainly i am not looking for OR i want all conditions to be true then want the results.

```
function GetSearchResults($user_id, $limit, $offset, $country = true) {
    $where_or = array();
    $where_and = array();
    $u = auth();

    // main query
    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `users`';

    // Filters
    $where = ' WHERE ( ';
    // must be verified
    $where_and[] = '`active` = "1"';
    //$where_and[] = '`privacy_show_profile_match_profiles` = "1"';

    //********** public search params *****************//
    // check gender from post or from session
    $genders = null;
    if( isset($_SESSION['_gender']) && $_SESSION['_gender'] !== '') {
        $genders = Secure( $_SESSION['_gender'] );
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_gender']) && $_POST['_gender'] !== '') {
        $_SESSION[ '_gender' ] = $_POST['_gender'];
        $genders = Secure( $_POST['_gender'] );
    }

    if( $genders == null || $genders == 'male' || $genders == 'female' ) {
        $genders = '4525, 4526';
    }

    if( is_array($genders)) {
        $genders = @implode( ',' , $genders );
    }

    if( strpos( $genders, ',' ) === false ) { 
        $where_and[] = '`gender` = "'. $genders .'"';
    } else {
        $where_and[] = '`gender` IN ('. $genders .')';
    }

    // check age from post or from session
    if(isset($_POST['_age_from']) && !empty($_POST['_age_from']) && isset($_POST['_age_to']) && !empty($_POST['_age_to']) ) {
        $where_and[] = 'DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 >= "'. Secure($_POST['_age_from']) .'" AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 <= "'. Secure($_POST['_age_to']) . '"';
    } else {
        if(isset( $_SESSION['_age_from'] ) && isset( $_SESSION['_age_to'] )) {
            $where_and[] = 'DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 >= "'. Secure($_SESSION['_age_from']) .'" AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 <= "'. Secure($_SESSION['_age_to']) . '"';
        } else {
            $where_and[] = 'DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 >= "20" AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 <= "55"';
        }
    }

    $query_country = '';
    if( $u->show_me_to == '' ) {
        if ((isset($_POST['_lat']) && !empty($_POST['_lat']) && isset($_POST['_lng']) && !empty($_POST['_lng']))
            ||
            (isset($_SESSION['_lat']) && !empty($_SESSION['_lat']) && isset($_SESSION['_lng']) && !empty($_SESSION['_lng']))
         ) {
             $lat = 0;
             $lng = 0;
             $located = 7;

             if(isset( $_SESSION['_lat'] ) ) $lat = Secure($_SESSION['_lat']);
             if(isset( $_POST['_lat'] ) ) $lat = Secure($_POST['_lat']);

             if( isset( $_SESSION['_lng'] ) ) $lng = Secure($_SESSION['_lng']);
             if( isset( $_POST['_lng'] ) ) $lng = Secure($_POST['_lng']);

             if( isset( $_SESSION['_located'] ) ) $located = Secure($_SESSION['_located']);
             if( isset( $_POST['_located'] ) ) $located = Secure($_POST['_located']);

             $distance = 'ROUND( ( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(' . $lng . ')) + sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) ,1) ';
             $where_and[] = $distance . ' <= ' . $located;
         }
    } else {
        if($country == true) {
            $query_country = ' OR `country` = "' . $u->show_me_to . '"';
            $where_and[] = '`country` = "' . $u->show_me_to . '"';
        }
    }

    //******************* Looks Filters ************************//
    if( isset($_POST['_height_from']) && !empty($_POST['_height_from']) && isset($_POST['_height_to']) && !empty($_POST['_height_to']) ) {
        $where_or[] = '`height` BETWEEN "'. Secure($_POST['_height_from']) .'" AND "'. Secure($_POST['_height_to']) .'"';
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_body']) && !empty($_POST['_body']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_body'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`body` = "'. Secure($_POST['_body']) . '"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`body` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_body']) .')';
        }
    }

    //******************* Background Filter ********************//
    if( isset($_POST['_language']) && !empty($_POST['_language']) ) {
        $where_or[] = '`language` = "'. Secure($_POST['_language']) .'"';
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_ethnicity']) && !empty($_POST['_ethnicity']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_ethnicity'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`ethnicity` = "'. Secure($_POST['_ethnicity']) . '"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`ethnicity` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_ethnicity']) .')';
        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_religion']) && !empty($_POST['_religion']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_religion'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`religion` = "'. Secure($_POST['_religion']) . '"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`religion` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_religion']) .')';
        }
    }

    //******************* LifeStyle filter *********************//
    if( isset($_POST['_relationship']) && !empty($_POST['_relationship']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_relationship'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`relationship` = "'. Secure($_POST['_relationship']) .'"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`relationship` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_relationship']) .')';
        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_smoke']) && !empty($_POST['_smoke']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_smoke'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`smoke` = "'. Secure($_POST['_smoke']) . '"';
        } else {  
            $where_or[] = '`smoke` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_smoke']) .')';
        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_drink']) && !empty($_POST['_drink']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_drink'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`drink` = "'. Secure($_POST['_drink']) . '"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`drink` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_drink']) .')';
        }
    }

    //******************* More Filter **************************//
    if( isset($_POST['_interest']) && !empty($_POST['_interest']) ) {
        $where_or[] = '`interest` like "%'. Secure($_POST['_interest']) .'%"';
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_education']) && !empty($_POST['_education']) ) { 
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_education'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`education` = "'. Secure($_POST['_education']) .   '"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`education` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_education']) .')';
        }
    }

    if( isset($_POST['_pets']) && !empty($_POST['_pets']) ) {
        if( strpos( Secure( $_POST['_pets'] ), ',' ) === false ) {
            $where_or[] = '`pets` = "'. Secure($_POST['_pets']) .'"';
        } else {
            $where_or[] = '`pets` IN ('. Secure($_POST['_pets']) .')';
        }
    }
if( !empty($where_or) ){
    $where = $where . '('. implode($where_or, ' AND ') . ') ';
}
if( !empty($where_and) ){
    if( !empty($where_or) ) {
        $where = $where . ' AND (' . implode($where_and, ' AND ') . ')';
    }else{
        $where = $where . ' (' . implode($where_and, ' AND ') . ')';
    }
}

if( isset( $_REQUEST['access_token'] ) ) {
    $uid = GetUserFromSessionID(Secure($_REQUEST['access_token']));
    $u->id = $uid;
}

if( isset( $u->id ) ) {
    // to exclude blocked users
    $notin = ' OR `id` NOT IN (SELECT `block_userid` FROM `blocks` WHERE `user_id` = ' . $u->id . ') ';
    // to exclude liked and disliked users users
    $notin .= ' OR `id` NOT IN (SELECT `like_userid` FROM `likes` WHERE `user_id` = ' . $u->id . ') ';
    $notin .= ' OR `id` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `likes` WHERE `like_userid` = ' . $u->id . ') ';
    $notin .= ' OR `id` <> "' . $u->id . '" ';
}

$custom_sql = [];
if(isset($_POST['custom_profile_data'])){
    $count = 100;
    for($i = 0 ; $i <= $count ; $i++ ){
        if(isset($_POST['fid_' . $i])){
            if(!empty($_POST['fid_' . $i])){
                $custom_sql[] = ' id IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `userfields` WHERE `fid_' . $i .'` = "'.Secure($_POST['fid_' . $i]) . '") ';
            }
        }
    }
}

$custom_sql_text = '';
if(!empty($custom_sql)){
    $custom_sql_text .= ' AND ( ';
    $custom_sql_text .= implode(' OR ', $custom_sql);
    $custom_sql_text .= ' ) ';
}

if( $limit == 0 ) {
    $limit = 20;
}
$orderBy = ' ORDER BY ';
$orderBy .= '`xlikes_created_at` DESC';
$orderBy .= ',`xvisits_created_at` DESC';
$orderBy .= ',`xmatches_created_at` DESC';
$orderBy .= ',`is_pro` DESC';
$query = $query . ' ' . $where . $notin . ') ' . $custom_sql_text . $query_country . $orderBy . ' LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset.';';
return $query;
```

}

Comment: Just a note about all your quoted numeric values: if `height` is a varchar/char/text/etc data type, "14000000" is between "139" and "170"... but that could give you more rows than you expect, not less.

Comment: MInd the SQL injections? As iam pretty sure the function `Secure()` is not that secure as it most likely is using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` without setting a charset first like the manual saids..

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks guys but it returns 0 rows http://prnt.sc/nuj8e9 even though i have varchar, please note that i have relevant data in the database that i am looking for using this query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the heads up! will check :)

Comment: This is where you should be looking [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), forget to mention the link in mine other comment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you very much :)

Comment: Change the first age check to `birthday <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 24 YEAR`; etc.  That gets rid of the leap year bug.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need distinct? usually users are unique

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `users`
```

Dont save numeric values as strings

```
`height` BETWEEN "139" AND "170"
```

You have the gender condition repeated: And I don't want to sound insensitive but those are a lot of genders.

```
`gender` IN (4525,4526,1275,1277,1278,1279,1280,1281,1282,1283)
```

You have 2 date diff, and second one doesn't have a comparator. Also Datediff return a numeric value not a string

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365 >= "24"
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `birthday`)/365  "16"
```

Now if the missing operator on `DATEDIFF` doesn't solve the problem. Go direct to the DB remove all conditions and start adding those one by one until you found which one cause return 0 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if execute the query one by one without AND operator it works fine, also where query contains more genders because in actual i have ability to add genders dynamically so i posted results of the query i have two genders in the code however that should not be the problem it should look for the available genders. also birthday is >=  "24" and <= "55" 16 query is for excluding already liked users, Thanks again.

Comment: You said thanks because you solve the problem? I dont see <= "55" on the code. If you keep adding conditions one by one which one cause to get 0 rows? BTW Im just talking about the first query. I think the php code is irrelevant. You should test the query direct on DB and then update the php code when you have a working query

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, sorry my bad i made mistake and wrote <= 16 however in actual its <= 55 while i was testing, however it didn't work when i execute queries one by one it works but the actual issue is when i execute with AND operator.

Comment: What you mean one by one? I mean add one run, add another run .... until you found the condition causing the error

Comment: For example SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `users`  WHERE (`height` BETWEEN "139" AND "170" AND `language` = "english");

Comment: Again, add conditions until you found the error. And I cant do anything else for you unless you provide sample data current and expected result.

Comment: Alright thanks but can you just confirm if i didn't make any mistake there please i mean in the code as it appears?

Comment: I wont check your code. You had to check your query first. Then you can fix your code.

Comment: Do you have any row in your table where all these conditions will be true? it might be just there is actually no data matching your above conditions.

Comment: Yes i have data that matches the query.

Comment: @Junaid data that matches **all** the conditions? Add sample data to the question, including rows you think should be included in the results.

Comment: Put it this way, if `DISTINCT *'` has any impact on a result set then you have far bigger problems to contend with!